# Is the compiler forced to evaluate if expressions depending on template parameters?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Consider this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {

    void f() { std::cout << "f"; }
    void g() { std::cout << "g"; }

    template <bool b>
    void call() { (b ? f() : g()); }
};

int main()
{
    A().call<true>();
}
```

Depending on the `template` paramter passed to `call`, either `f` or `g` will be called. My question is, if the compiler is somehow forced to pre-evaluate the if condition. Consider this other possible implementation of `call`:

```
template <bool b>
void call() { 
    bool x = b;    
    (x ? f() : g()); 
}
```

In this case, the compile-time template is first converted into a runtime variable, before the decision on `f` or `g` is made. I would assume, that the compiler would not be able to remove the if statement in this case.

Indeed, if I test this behaviour with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zP6i8n) that seems to be exactly what happens.

Is there some part of the standard that defines which template expressions *have* to be evaluated at compile-time?

(Of course, in this simple example, I could easily write specializations for `b == true` and `b == false`, but that is not what this question is about.)

Comment: As far as I know neither of those are required to be evaluated at compile time. You can use constexpr if statements to force them to be done at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All template expressions are evaluated at compile time, because templates don't exist at runtime. You can use `if constexpr` which is garantueed to be evaluated at compile time:

```
template <bool b>
void call() { if constexpr (b) f(); else g(); }
```

In you example (for `b = true`) this will become

```
void call() { f(); }
```

regardless of optimization level.

However when you use a normal `if` or a ternary operator the generated code might be easily optimized. In your example (again for `b=true`) template instantion creates something like this:

```
void call() { (true ? f() : g()); }
```

which the compiler can easily optimize if you allow him to. G++ with `-O3` for example just removes the instantion of `A` and the call to `call` alltogether and just moves `std::cout << "f"` into `main`. See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PqZvX-).

---

Concolusion: All template expressions are evaluated at compile time, but the compiler can recognize if an expression or variable is constant and is able to optimize such cases, but the compiler is not obliged to do so (you don't want optimized code when you try to debug something)